# Can you measure hall voltage for holes and electrons in the same time?

Tags: hall-effect

I have an experiment on hall effect, and the goal is to determine hall coefficient and determine what type of the material it is, using Uh=f(B) graph. The table of results show two columns of measure for one material, the first column represents hall voltage variation for holes (?) and the second column shows hall voltage variation for electrons. First of all I'm not sure what the voltages exactly are, since as far as I know when measuring hall voltage we can measure it either for electrons or holes and from it we can calculate hall coefficient, and not measuring both charge carriers voltage at the same time, so this is the first thing I didn't quite understand.
The second part is when I tried to calculate hall coefficient by tracing the graph I found myself facing a problem, since I have "two" hall voltages, one for holes and one for electros means there is two hall coefficient to calculate, and I don't see how this is possible, since the goal is to determine the type of the material by knowing the sign of hall coefficient "Rh"... But I tried to go on with the calculations, I found that the plot of the graph for "holes voltage" (if this term is correct) as function of magnetic field negative, which when calculating the hall coefficient will give me a negative result, and form what I understand hall coefficient for holes should be positive, and the same goes when I traced the graph for "electrons voltage" as function of magnetic field I found positive hall coefficient, so I found myself in a contradiction and couldn't determine what type of the material I have.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.[image]
[image]

Comment: The same semiconductor with different dopants can have positive or negative majority carriers, depending on the dopant.

Comment: Thank you sir for you reply, I do understand that, but I'm facing issue to determine what the majority carriers are. By using the hall coeffiecient relation Rh=1/p.e for holes and Rh=-1/n.e for electrons I can calculate the concentration, but in my case I found that Rh gives negative value for both of holes and electrons (I can compare the value to determine which charge carrier has the most concetration) but having Rh with negative value for both electrons and holes didn't seem right and logical to me. Plus, I need to determine the sign of the charge carriers.

Comment: (Follow up to my preivous comment) Since both charge carriers have negative concetration, means that electrons and holes have the same sign, which is a contradiction  with the theory.